# avoid the slash?

Tags: american-english, british-english, writing, sentence-patterns, slash

Should the slash be avoided?

For example `every week/day` in my head is translated to `every week or day`. I think I started using slashes because I saw them used in forums and in articles.

Is using slashes U.S. specific, while British English is against it? Or do I understand it wrong?

*P.S. If you find any spelling errors here, please let me know.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most style guides recommend against using the slash in phrases like “X and/or Y”, as well as  “this is hard/impossible to do”. In particular, scientific publications now have strong policies against this ramping-up use, because it allows for a lot of imprecision in the writing, and weakens the scientific discussion. I know that is the case in the world of physics and chemistry publishing, and [this entry](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2009/07/to-slashnot-to-slashthat-is-the-questionquandary.html), for example, seems to indicate it is so in other fields.

The one place I find it's gained real traction in both written and spoken language is when it's used in, e.g., “he was a comedian-slash-banjo player”, where it is now often spelt out as here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your sentence will be clearer if you write the actual word instead of the slash.

Slash could be interpreted as *or*, *per*, *a*, etc. But if you use the actual word there is no confusion.

Note that with some standard metric names (e.g. km/h, m/s, etc.) in particular, you can use slash because the meaning will be understood by any reader.

Comment: When you still want to avoid the slash in metric names, you should spell them completely: kilometers per hour, instead of km per h.

Comment: Constructs such as "km per h" are expressly forbidden by the [SI brochure](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter5/5-1.html "BIPM").  In an expression like "km/h" you're effectively writing a formula, where the "km" and the "h" represent mathematical entities and the slash ("solidus") represents division; this is not the same as using a slash between words in prose.